# How to use variable of method from 1 class in 2 class via Java?

Tags: java, variables, methods

```
public static class One {

    @Override
    public String interact(String... values) {
        String actualTextOne = "test";
        return actualTextOne;
    }
}

public static class Two {

    @Override
    public String interact(String... values) {
        String actualTextTwo = "test";

        /*    Here I need to compare actualTextOne and actualTextTwo, but the problem is that I can't find solluction how to use actualTextOne in Two class*/

        return actualTextTwo;
    }
}
```

Comment: pass it as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.
Please check variable scope in java.
https://www.codecademy.com/articles/variable-scope-in-java

---

A possible solution here is to call the method `interact` from the class `One`. Something like this

```
public static class Two {

    @Override
    public String interact(String... values) {
        String actualTextTwo = "test";

        One one = new One();
        String actualTextOne = one.interact(values);
        
        // compare values here

        return actualTextTwo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any solutions for such purpose?

Comment: I updated my answer with a possible approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why in your classes functions have parameters if you dont use it?
2. You can mark your class with static only if he is nested, else you need do like this:

   ```
    class Two {
    static public String interact(String... values) {
        String actualTextTwo = "test";
        return actualTextTwo;
    }
   ```

   }
3. String textOne = One.interact("");
   String textTwo = Two.interact("");
   System.out.println(textOne==textTwo);